# Execute another python script, then shut down current script

Tags: python, subprocess, sys

I have a python script `script_a.py` that uses `subprocess.call()` that executes another script `script_b.py` as it's last instruction before ending. I need `script_b.py` to wait until `script_a.py` closes before proceeding with its own instructions. For this I am using a while loop within `script_b.py`. How can I do this? All of my current solutions I have tried have `script_a.py` waiting until `script_b.py` is finished before it closes itself. I have a feeling this might involve `atexit()` or something similar, but I am lost.

Many thanks!

Comment: it sounds like you are using the wrong construct ... I think you want `os.exec*` instead of `subprocess` ...

Comment: Got it. In the event that `script_b.py` has everything it needs to run defined within itself, then what am I expected to pass in the list of args that the exec* functions force me to pass?

Comment: you can probably just pass the ["python","script_b.py"] ... its been a while since i have done that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make some totally hacky crap

**script_b.py**

```
while not os.path.exists("a.done"):pass
time.sleep(0.2) # a little longer just to be really sure ...
os.remove("a.done")
... # rest of script b
```

**script_a.py**

```
import atexit
atexit.register(lambda *a:open("a.done","w"))
```

---

or instead of `Popen` just do

```
os.execl("/usr/bin/python","script_b.py")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script_a.py would be:

```
import subprocess
#do whatever stuff you want here
p = subprocess.Popen(["python","b.py"])
p.wait()
p.terminate()

#continue doing stuff
```

Comment: Where does this close `script_a.py` so the subprocess p can do its work?

Comment: Sorry I read it the other way around. If _a_ calls _b_ in the last instruction, and b needs to wait until a finishes you have an infinite loop. Just use another script _c_ that calls _a_ and then _b_. Any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: So there is no way to force script_a to continue on with its next instruction (which is `sis.exit()` regardless of when script_b finishes?

Comment: Use a script _c_ that calls both.